# Why deconstructing in Func<KeyValuePair,T> doesn't work, although having a Deconstruct extension method?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

In the following example, in function `Test()`, the first line compiles successfully, while the second doesn't, even though I have a `Deconstruct` extension method for `KeyValuePair`. Why is that?

```
public static class Tests {
    class Foo { }
    class Bar { }

    public  static void Test() {
        // This works:
        Bar[] works = new List<ValueTuple<Foo, Bar>>()
            .Select(((Foo foo, Bar bar) t) => t.bar).ToArray();

        // But this doesn't, albeit having a `Deconstruct` extension method:
        Bar[] fails = new List<KeyValuePair<Foo, Bar>>()
            .Select(((Foo foo, Bar bar) i) => i.bar).ToArray();
    }

    public static void Deconstruct<TKey, TVal>(this KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> tuple, out TKey key, out TVal value) {
        key = tuple.Key;
        value = tuple.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a list of key value pairs, not a list of `(Foo, Bar)` tuples, so your `.Select(...)` has the wrong signature.  You aren't calling `Deconstuct` anywhere.

Comment: The `Select` call with the tuple isn't deconstructing anything - it's just declaring a tuple variable `t`. Basically, you can't deconstruct as part of declaring a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deconstructing is a feature specifically for assigning values to variables.  In your code you're not assigning values for variables, so deconstruction can't be happening.  You can just use a deconstruction of a type anywhere that type would be expected (in this case, as the parameter of an anonymous function), you can only deconstruct it *when assigning to variables*.

There is no deconstruction happening for the first select that actually uses tuples, that's just the syntax for a value tuple.  It's not deconstruction (despite looking so similar; the features *were designed* to look similar, but they're technically different features).